# How to make the methods in third party dll visible in vb6?

Tags: .net, dll, vb6

I have my C#.net class library(`MyLib.dll`). MyLib.dll is calling other third party dll(`Other.dll`) file which is added through reference to my class library(MyLib.dll).

Now the problem is that `MyLib.dll` is to be used in vb 6.0.

I've registered `MyLib.dll` to enable COM and also i've set the `Register for COM Interop` option in Properties of my Class Library.

Also I've generated `.tlb` file for `MyLib.dll` (using `Regasm`)and for `Other.dll` to make them visible in COM. 
I could see both the `MyLib and Other` in References of vb6.

The methods in the `MyLib` are visible but methods in `Other` are not visible when opened with vb6.

I've also tried to place MyLib in GAC but `Other.dll`(Third party dll) doesnot support vb6, it only supports for C#.net as well as VB.Net.

How to make the methods in the `Other.dll` visible in vb6.

Is there any way to make the methods in the third party dll to visible?

Comment: Just because you ran Other.dll through TlbExport doesn't mean all the objects and methods inside are exposed. Inspect the Other.tlb using OLEView to see if it worked as expected. Post the IDL for additional help.

Comment: This requires applying attributes to the classes in Other.dll.  If you don't have the source code for it then you cannot do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I dont have the source code of it

Comment: Again I think my answer is your best option, if you don't have the source to Other.dll. Make "shadow" functions or methods on MyLib (the accessible one) that just call the real functions or methods on Other.dll (the inaccesible one) and receive the results. Then you can pass those results to VB6, or manipulate them, store them or whatever... In short: make a **wrapper** for Other.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood you correctly, MyLib.dll is visible from COM, but Other.dll is not. But, if Other.dll is visible from MyLib.dll you could use MyLib.dll as a bridge between Other.dll and COM.

Say Other.dll has a void Foo(int x, string y) function you want exposed to COM. Make a function on MyLib.dll like so

```
public void Foo(int x, string y)
{
    Other.Foo(x, y);
}
```

Would't this work?

Comment: Other.dll is also visible in COM . MyLib.dll uses functions in Other.dll. It is not working though